# Batch file parameter not accepting arguments run time

Tags: batch-file, parameters, echo

Learning about batch files and wrote this simple program

```
@echo off
Rem why doesn't this work?
echo Welcome %1
pause
```

When it runs this is the output:
    Welcome
    Press any key to continue . . .

Why doesn't it let me enter anything for the parameter value? Thanks.
This is on windows 10 btw.

Comment: Because it's expecting it on the command line, like `C:\>mybatch.bat grant2088`. That's where %1 comes from. You're not telling it to prompt you for input.

Comment: excellent thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%1` (and `%2`, `%3`, and so on) represent parameters passed into the batch file when you run it, as Ken White alluded to. So, if you saved this file as go.cmd...

```
@echo off
echo hello %1
echo hello %2
echo hello %3
```

...and then ran at the command prompt: `go paula agnus denise`, you would get this:

```
> go paula agnus denise
hello paula
hello agnus
hello denise
```

If you want to be able to ask the user to enter text during execution, instead of entering it at the command line, then you need to use `SET /p`. Example:

```
@echo off
set /p name=What is your name? 
echo Welcome, %name%.
```

Run that, enter Gary, and you get something like this:

```
What is your name? Gary
Welcome, Gary.
```